# listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3001 on npm run JHipster Spring Boot + Angular project

Tags: angular, spring-boot, npm, jhipster, webpack-dev-server

Below is the error message I'm getting on **`nmp run`** in JHipster Spring Boot + Angular project, thought to change this port manually, but could not find **3001** port anywhere in the project, deleted **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** file, reran **npm install** command but that also didn't help.

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 149404ms                                                                                                                     12:11:04 AM

i ｢wdm｣:    493 modules
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:9060
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:9000
    External: http://192.168.137.1:9000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 --------------------------------------
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3001
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1296:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1449:7)
    at Object.startServer [as fn] (D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\async.js:123:39)
    at D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\UI.js:184:14
    at iterate (D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\async-each-series\index.js:8:5)
    at D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\async-each-series\index.js:16:16
    at D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\UI.js:192:13
    at Object.setUrlOptions [as fn] (D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\async.js:76:9)
    at D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\UI.js:184:14
    at iterate (D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\async-each-series\index.js:8:5)
    at D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\async-each-series\index.js:16:16
    at D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\UI.js:192:13
    at Object.setBsOptions [as fn] (D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\async.js:48:9)
    at D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\browser-sync-ui\lib\UI.js:184:14
    at iterate (D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\async-each-series\index.js:8:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3001
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack-dev-server: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.dev.js" "--inline" "--hot" "--port=9060" "--watch-content-base" "--env.stats=minimal"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack-dev-server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-21T18_41_11_152Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:dev: `npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-21T18_41_11_255Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start: `npm run webpack:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-21T18_41_11_388Z-debug.log
```

> **1st Logfile** 2020-04-21T18_41_11_152Z-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'webpack-dev-server',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--config',
1 verbose cli   'webpack/webpack.dev.js',
1 verbose cli   '--inline',
1 verbose cli   '--hot',
1 verbose cli   '--port=9060',
1 verbose cli   '--watch-content-base',
1 verbose cli   '--env.stats=minimal'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.2
4 verbose run-script [
4 verbose run-script   'prewebpack-dev-server',
4 verbose run-script   'webpack-dev-server',
4 verbose run-script   'postwebpack-dev-server'
4 verbose run-script ]
5 info lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~prewebpack-dev-server: problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
6 info lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack-dev-server: problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
7 verbose lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack-dev-server: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack-dev-server: PATH: D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\.bin;D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\.bin;D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter;D:\Installed\Python36\Scripts\;D:\Installed\Python36\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Installed\AndroidStudio\Sdk\platform-tools;D:\Installed\OpenCV\OpenCV_3.4.1\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin;D:\Installed\Java\javaEE_8\glassfish5\bin;D:\Installed\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Installed\xampp\htdocs\;D:\Installed\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Installed\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;D:\Installed\Java\JavaSE_1.8.0\jdk1.8.0_192\bin;D:\Installed\Java\JavaSE_1.8.0\jdk1.8.0_192\jre\bin;D:\Installed\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin\startup.bat;D:\Installed\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin\shutdown.bat;D:\Installed\Java\jboss-sec-6.X\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Installed\Git\cmd;D:\Installed\Git\bin;D:\Installed\Go\bin;E:\ProjectWorkspace\HyperLedgerWorkspace\HyperLedgerFabricSamples\fabric-samples\bin;D:\Installed\curl-7.66.0-win64-mingw\bin;D:\Installed\Java\jdk1.7.0_80;D:\Installed\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre;D:\Installed\DataBase\PostgreSQLPortable\pgsql12\bin;D:\Installed\DataBase\PostgreSQLPortable\pgsql12;D:\Installed\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\;D:\Installed\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\npm-global;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Voyager\go\bin;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack-dev-server: CWD: D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack
10 silly lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack-dev-server: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.dev.js" "--inline" "--hot" "--port=9060" "--watch-content-base" "--env.stats=minimal"'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack-dev-server: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack-dev-server: Failed to exec webpack-dev-server script
13 verbose stack Error: problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack-dev-server: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.dev.js" "--inline" "--hot" "--port=9060" "--watch-content-base" "--env.stats=minimal"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
15 verbose cwd D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "webpack-dev-server" "--" "--config" "webpack/webpack.dev.js" "--inline" "--hot" "--port=9060" "--watch-content-base" "--env.stats=minimal"
18 verbose node v12.16.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack-dev-server: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.dev.js" "--inline" "--hot" "--port=9060" "--watch-content-base" "--env.stats=minimal"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack-dev-server script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

> **2nd Log file** 2020-04-21T18_41_11_255Z-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'webpack:dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewebpack:dev', 'webpack:dev', 'postwebpack:dev' ]
5 info lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~prewebpack:dev: problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
6 info lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack:dev: problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
7 verbose lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack:dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack:dev: PATH: D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\.bin;D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter;D:\Installed\Python36\Scripts\;D:\Installed\Python36\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Installed\AndroidStudio\Sdk\platform-tools;D:\Installed\OpenCV\OpenCV_3.4.1\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin;D:\Installed\Java\javaEE_8\glassfish5\bin;D:\Installed\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Installed\xampp\htdocs\;D:\Installed\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Installed\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;D:\Installed\Java\JavaSE_1.8.0\jdk1.8.0_192\bin;D:\Installed\Java\JavaSE_1.8.0\jdk1.8.0_192\jre\bin;D:\Installed\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin\startup.bat;D:\Installed\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin\shutdown.bat;D:\Installed\Java\jboss-sec-6.X\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Installed\Git\cmd;D:\Installed\Git\bin;D:\Installed\Go\bin;E:\ProjectWorkspace\HyperLedgerWorkspace\HyperLedgerFabricSamples\fabric-samples\bin;D:\Installed\curl-7.66.0-win64-mingw\bin;D:\Installed\Java\jdk1.7.0_80;D:\Installed\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre;D:\Installed\DataBase\PostgreSQLPortable\pgsql12\bin;D:\Installed\DataBase\PostgreSQLPortable\pgsql12;D:\Installed\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\;D:\Installed\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\npm-global;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Voyager\go\bin;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack:dev: CWD: D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack
10 silly lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack:dev: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack:dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~webpack:dev: Failed to exec webpack:dev script
13 verbose stack Error: problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:dev: `npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
15 verbose cwd D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "webpack:dev"
18 verbose node v12.16.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:dev: `npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

> **3rd Logfile** 2020-04-21T18_41_11_388Z-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~prestart: problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
6 info lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~start: problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
7 verbose lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~start: PATH: D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter;D:\Installed\Python36\Scripts\;D:\Installed\Python36\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Installed\AndroidStudio\Sdk\platform-tools;D:\Installed\OpenCV\OpenCV_3.4.1\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin;D:\Installed\Java\javaEE_8\glassfish5\bin;D:\Installed\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Installed\xampp\htdocs\;D:\Installed\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Installed\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;D:\Installed\Java\JavaSE_1.8.0\jdk1.8.0_192\bin;D:\Installed\Java\JavaSE_1.8.0\jdk1.8.0_192\jre\bin;D:\Installed\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin\startup.bat;D:\Installed\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin\shutdown.bat;D:\Installed\Java\jboss-sec-6.X\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Installed\Git\cmd;D:\Installed\Git\bin;D:\Installed\Go\bin;E:\ProjectWorkspace\HyperLedgerWorkspace\HyperLedgerFabricSamples\fabric-samples\bin;D:\Installed\curl-7.66.0-win64-mingw\bin;D:\Installed\Java\jdk1.7.0_80;D:\Installed\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre;D:\Installed\DataBase\PostgreSQLPortable\pgsql12\bin;D:\Installed\DataBase\PostgreSQLPortable\pgsql12;D:\Installed\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\;D:\Installed\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\npm-global;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Voyager\go\bin;C:\Users\Voyager\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~start: CWD: D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack
10 silly lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run webpack:dev' ]
11 silly lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start: `npm run webpack:dev`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Installed\WebDevelopment\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
15 verbose cwd D:\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\JavaEE-STS\ProblemStackWorkspace\ProblemStack
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Installed\\WebDevelopment\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start: `npm run webpack:dev`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the problem-stack@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Change your question topic it's saying `0.0.0.0:300`

Comment: Have you use the find function in your code editor or ide to search through the whole project directories for port `3001`

Comment: @AvivLo yes I did, found nothing

Answer (score 1):

I got this fixed by disabling one of my Bluetooth adaptor from network connections folder(`Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`).

If you're experiencing this issue, try disabling some of the network adaptors that you have available, try the Bluetooth one first before disabling others.

[Source](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1668)

Comment: This is the working solution for me. In my case, I disabled all other adapters, too, including vm network adapters. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a rogue process running in the background from a previous run. If you are on Windows you could open the TaskManager and look for node processes that are still runnning.
Else you could try to figure out which process is using the port by using powershell with this command:

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort portNumber).OwningProcess
```

or in Linux:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

Comment: I thought too but unfortunately, there's no process running on this port, I tried this and few other PowerShell scripts.